# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function twentynineteen_post_thumbnail()

Tags: fatal-error

I was trying to update the theme on one of my Wordpress websites and suddenly I got this error on both my Wordpress website on the same web hosting (even the one I was not working with !!)
At first, I got this error: The site is experiencing technical difficulties. After disabling all plugins and switching to the 2019 theme, this error showed up.
I have no idea how to solve this issue. I contacted to host admin and they-they said this is a Wordpress issue and not related to the host!

I look forward to hearing from someone to help. Thanks

Comment: Check This Link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023112/php-error-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method.

Comment: That function should be there: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.2.2/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/inc/template-tags.php#L135 I'd guess your copy of the theme is broken somehow. Can you try re-uploading it? You're just using the theme as-is - you don't have an additional child theme? Can you try a different theme? Can you download the whole site to reproduce the problem locally where you can debug it?